# unmarshall json using dynamic key

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I'm receiving a `json` object that has a known-static structure inside a key that varies between 10 different values.

Consider `lastname` can be any in a list of 10 lastnames:

```
var lastnames = [...]string { "Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Brown", "Jones", "Miller", "Davis", "Garcia", "Rodriguez", "Wilson" }
```

Now, this is how the `json` looks:

```
{ 
  (lastname here): 
    {
        "position": value,
        "user_email": value
    }
}
```

I tried to unmarshall it using the following structs, but I only get null values:

```
type Inside struct {
    Rol   string   `json:"position"`
    Email   string   `json:"user_email"`
}

type Outside struct {
    Key Inside
}

...
var outside Outside
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &outside)
```

Is it possible to unmarshall this directly without creating 10 different structs? Is there possible workaround?

Comment: Use a map, ie `map[string]Inside`.

Comment: you mean in the var @mkopriva ? var map[string]Inside ?

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/pPNflEMnWlY

Comment: thanks @mkopriva, that worked